# Android unchecked checkbox in filtering ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-checkbox

this below code for filtering listView is currect and dont have any problem. but after search and checked checkboxs and press BackSpace on android keyboard to clear characters and of String to start, all checkbox unchecked, i dont want to have this ability and i want to listView was checked when search or clear searchable EditText.

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactListStructure>  implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> item = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> originalList;
    private NameFilter filter;
    public ContactsAdapter (ArrayList<ContactListStructure> data) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.send_sms, data);
        item = data;
        originalList = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
        originalList.addAll(data);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        ContactListStructure item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_sms, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private  CheckBox   chk_name_mobile;
        private  ImageView  photo;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            chk_name_mobile = (CheckBox)  view.findViewById(R.id.chk_name_mobile);
            photo           = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        }

        public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<ContactListStructure> adapter, final ContactListStructure item, final int position) {
            chk_name_mobile.setText ( item.name );
            if( item.checked ){
                chk_name_mobile.setChecked( true );
                if( item.photo != null ) photo.setImageBitmap(item.photo);
            }else{
                chk_name_mobile.setChecked( false );
                if( item.photo == null )
                    photo.setImageDrawable( G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user) );
                else
                    photo.setImageBitmap(item.photo);
            }

            chk_name_mobile.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if( isChecked ){
                   item.checked = true;
               }else{
                   item.checked = false;
               }
                   }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter  = new NameFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }
    private class NameFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<ContactListStructure> filteredItems = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
                for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    ContactListStructure nameList = originalList.get(i);
                    if(nameList.name.toString ().contains(constraint)) {
                        filteredItems.add ( nameList );
                    }
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            item = (ArrayList<ContactListStructure>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = item.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(item.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the code for you.   First read and understand the code, then use it in your program :)

```
Model Class:

package com.example.model;

public class ContactListStructure {
String name;
boolean check;

public ContactListStructure(String name, boolean check) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.check = check;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public boolean isCheck() {
    return check;
}
public void setCheck(boolean check) {
    this.check = check;
}


}


In main activity;

namesarrayList=new Arraylist<ContactListStructure >();

ContactListStructure conliststruct;
for(int i=0;i<namesarray.length();i++)
{
    conliststruct=new ContactListStructure(namesarray[i], false);
    namesarrayList.add(conliststruct);
}
ContactsAdapter adapter=new ContactsAdapter (namesarrayList);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);





Adapter Class:

public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactListStructure>  implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> filteritemList = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> originalList;
    private NameFilter filter;
    private  CheckBox   chk_name_mobile;
    private  ImageView  photo;



    public ContactsAdapter (ArrayList<ContactListStructure> data) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.send_sms, data);

        this.originalList = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
        originalList.addAll(data);
        this.filteritemList = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>(originalList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos=position;

        ContactListStructure item = (ContactListStructure)getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_sms, parent, false);


        } else {

        }

        chk_name_mobile = (CheckBox)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_name_mobile);
        photo           = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        chk_name_mobile.setText(item.getName().toString());
        chk_name_mobile.setChecked(item.isCheck());
        chk_name_mobile.setTag(item);

     chk_name_mobile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                 ContactListStructure itemobj=(ContactListStructure) cb.getTag();


                if (originalList.get(Integer.valueOf(pos)).isCheck()) {
                    cb.setSelected(false);
                    originalList.get(Integer.valueOf(pos)).setCheck(false);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    cb.setSelected(true);
                    originalList.get(Integer.valueOf(pos)).setCheck(true);      
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                //region.setCheck(chkItem.isChecked());
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null){
            filter  = new NameFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }
    private class NameFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
            {
                ArrayList<ContactListStructure> filteredItems = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
                for(int i = 0, l = filteritemList.size(); i < l; i++)
                {
                    ContactListStructure nameList = filteritemList.get(i);
                    if(nameList.name.toString ().contains(constraint)) {
                        filteredItems.add ( nameList );
                    }
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = filteritemList;
                    result.count = filteritemList.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            originalList = (ArrayList<ContactListStructure>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(originalList.get(i));
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir. i get this error: `Error:(42, 47) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isCheck()`

Comment: I've added a sample model class. Dont copy paste everything. Just use the logic I've used there. P.S: Dont call me Sir.Im a beginner; :)

Comment: items dont checked currectly. for example after check in one item some items checked

Comment: Ive updated the code. Read it and understand the logic then use it in your program :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same that why does this happen and also I had attached the source for the same. So, you can get it from [ListView with CheckBox Scrolling Issue](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)